# compare the two files

Tags: linux, file-comparison

Please suggest how can we compare two files having major part similar but in a jumbled way.
example:

`A file` has

```
72444 55555
72445 55666
55666 72446
```

`B File` has

```
72444 55555
55666 72446
72445 55666
xxxxx yyyyy
```

So, I only want to get the difference in the output file file along with the name of the file having the error. may be like below, if rest of the above contents are same.

```
B File xxxxx yyyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

The `comm` utility may extract the lines unique to either file or common to both.  The utility requires that both files are sorted, which takes care of the issue with "jumbled lines".

The `comm` utility's default output is in three tab-delimited columns:

1. Lines only found in the first file.
2. Lines only found in the second file.
3. Lines found in both files.

One may disable a column by using `-1`, `-2`, or `-3`.

Here, I'm using two process substitutions to generate sorted input data for `comm` and asking it only to show the first two columns, i.e. data that is unique to either file.

```bash
$ comm -3 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
        xxxxx yyyyy
```

```bash
$ comm -3 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) | cut -f 2-
xxxxx yyyyy
```

As you can see, the second column is the only one that contains something, so we may conclude that the line `xxxxx yyyyy` only occurs in `fileB` and that all other lines are common to both files.

Without `-3` we also see the common lines in the third column:

```bash
$ comm <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
                55666 72446
                72444 55555
                72445 55666
        xxxxx yyyyy
```

Comment: I sorted the files and tried with grep -vwFf file A-file B-file, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @SuryaShukla No, I'm not entirely surprised.  You could use `grep -vxF -f <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)` but it's terribly inefficient compared to using `comm`.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you can use its array subtraction operators:

```
$ a='A file' b='B file'
$ al=( ${(f)"$(<$a)"} ) bl=( ${(f)"$(<$b)"} )
$ print -rC1 -- "$a "${^al:|bl} "$b "${^bl:|al}
B file xxxxx yyyyy
```

Where:

- `$(<file)` expands to the contents of `file` without the trailing newlines
- `${(f)expansion}` splits it on newlines, discarding empty elements, so `$al` and `$bl` contain the non-empty lines of `A file` and `B file` respectively.
- `${a:|b}` expands to the elements of the `a` array except (bar) those that are also in `b` (array subtraction).
- `text${^array}` when `array=(a b)` expands to `texta` `textb` instead of `texta` `b`. Here we use it to prefix the file name to the elements resulting of the array subtractions.
- `print -rC1 --` `print`s each of its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn

Note that if there are several occurrences of the same line in both files, that won't be reported even if there's not the same number of occurrences in both.